# Inducing coil current by falling?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Typically, if a rod or coil is moved at a constant velocity through a constant magnetic field, a motional EMF will be induced by Faraday's Law but no current because there is no net emf or no closed circuit.

[image]

However, what is the coil was being consonantly accelerated (falling in uniform gravitational field with no drag)? Would it still produce only a motional EMF like with constant velocity or would there be a current induced? I think that there would be no current because wouldn't the flux through the coil be constant through time and thus causing the same motional EMF issue as above?